# C struct, union pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, casting, struct, unions

I have a typedeffed struct and an union. The union contains the struct and a single `uint32_t`. The goal is to assign a value to `foo` that corresponds to the 'bits' in the struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t valA :1;
    uint32_t valB :1;
    uint32_t valC :1;
    uint32_t valD :1;
    uint32_t valE :1;
} ValStruct_Type;

typedef union {
    ValStruct_Type valStruct;
    uint32_t valUint;
} ValUnion_Type;

uint32_t foo = 0;


int main(void)
{
    ValStruct_Type Vals;
    Vals.valA = 0x0;
    Vals.valB = 0x1;
    Vals.valC = 0x0;
    Vals.valD = 0x1;
    Vals.valE = 0x1;

    ValStruct_Type *Vals_ptr;
    Vals_ptr = &Vals;

    foo = ((ValUnion_Type *)Vals_ptr)->valUint;

    return 0;
}
```

foo becomes:

```
Decimal:    4194330
Hex:        0x40001a
Binary:     10000000000000000011010
```

Who can explain what is happening here exactly (union pointer to a struct pointer, defererenced to a union member?)?

Secondly: why is bit 22 of `foo` set in addition to bit 1,3 and 4?

Comment: Try `memset`ing `Vals` to zero before assigning to it.

Comment: The ValStructType defines a 5 bit field which you set to 11010. The valUint is a 32 bit field.  The Union will assign enough storage for the larger of the two but does not initialise that storage.  So you never initialised ->valUint and I guess the 1 in the most sig bit is just garbage. The most significant 27 bits will not be initialised by your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit 22 is set due to undefined behavior. You've created a local variable that you never fully initialized, and you then set 5 bits of it. The remaining bits are whatever they happen to be, which is the case with uninitialized locals.

Regarding the first part of your question... what isn't clear? Your question (`union pointer to a struct pointer, defererenced to a union member`) seems to answer itself. Casting something to the type it already is doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Thanks for that. It has indeed to do with the local variable being unitialzed. Is there a better way than using memset to initialize it to 0?

Comment: @wlamers `ValStruct_Type Vals = {0};`

Comment: Indeed seems to do the trick also on GCC. I expected that would only set the first bitfiled to 0, but it actually sets the whole memory space to 0.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a union you instruct the compiler to reserve enough memory for any instances that can fit either of it's members.

When you typedef a bitfield it is padded to some byte size (normally 4 or 8 bytes, but could be 1 byte in your small case).

Since you only allocated enough memory for your struct (check with `sizeof(ValStruct_Type)`) and then cast it to a union taking up more memory you got undefined behaviour.

Whatever filled up that part of your stack was copied into `foo`.

What you approximately did equals to

```
char a = 0x1a;
int foo = *(int *)&a;
```

To get the correct behaviour you need to

- allocate the union
- initialise it
- then start setting your bitfield.

Comment: I see no reason to believe `sizeof(ValStruct_Type) > sizeof(ValUnion_Type)` in this case, since depending on the compiler, `sizeof(ValStruct_Type)` is either equal to `sizeof(uint32_t)` or equal to `5*sizeof(uint32_t)`, and overlaying a single `uint_t` on top of that isn't any larger.

Comment: No, most likely (but double check it please) `sizeof(ValStruct_Type) = 1 < sizeof(ValUnion_Type) = 4`. The whole point of bitfields is to pack those bits as compact as possible. 5 bits can be packed into one byte.

Comment: On my compiler, `sizeof(ValStruct_Type) == 4`: _gcc version 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2) (GCC)_ letting my initial assertion stand.

Comment: I stand corrected. In this case - initialise your struct before filling the bitfields. `memset(&Vals, 0, sizeof(Vals))` and you will get the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Both the size of the struct and union appear to be 4. You mention to allocate memory for some union and initialize it. But I do not have a union variable at all. I only use a cast to a declared (not defined) union. Can you explain in more detail what you mean?

Comment: @wlamers what he means is your simple cast is working out of sheer luck and not the way you really want to do this. It works because it turns out they're the same size, but if you were to change the union size in the future you would probably forget to change this code and that would lead to undefined behavior (UB). UB is often one of the most difficult causes of crashing code to locate.

Comment: I agree with that. Besides I get the feeling this is all implementation dependant also (and indeed K&R confirms). Any clue how to accomplish this functionality and still using bitfields?