# Attempting to allocate a union to a void* in a struct

Tags: c, typedef, unions, void-pointers

The goal is to create a structure that contains 3 fields. One of those fields needs to be a `uint32_t union` but the flags will be different for each element. I believe the best way to do this is to create a separate `union` for each peripheral and assign it to a void pointer in the parent struct (somehow).

The Current Plan:

```
//--------------Register for AAA
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint32_t spare  : 32;  //< Bits 0-31 not used
    }Bits;
    
    uint32_t FullData;
}ABC_EMPTY_DATA;
ABC_EMPTY_DATA AAA_Data;

//--------------Register for BBB
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint32_t use32BitColor          :  1;  //< Bit0 
        uint32_t enableTimer            :  1;  //< Bit1 
        uint32_t fooTheBar              :  1;   //< Bit2
        uint32_t spare                  : 29;  //< Bits 3-31 not used
    }Bits;
    
    uint32_t FullData;
}ABC_BBB_DATA;
ABC_EMPTY_DATA BBB_Data;

//--------------Register for CCC
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint32_t useInternalFrameTick   :  1;  //< Bit0 
        uint32_t useExternalFrameTick   :  1;  //< Bit1 
        uint32_t spare                  : 30;  //< Bits 2-31 not used
    }Bits;
    
    uint32_t FullData;
}ABC_CCC_DATA;
ABC_CCC_DATA CCC_Data;  

//-------The Peripherals with register element
typedef struct
{
    char                *Name;
    unsigned int        HexCmd;
    void                *Data; //Connect to corasponding XXXX_Data  
    
}ABC_dataStructs;

//----- Initializing Peripherals
typedef struct
{
    ABC_dataStructs AAA  = {.Name = "AAA",  .HexCmd = 0x00,     .Data = (void*) &AAA_Data}; 
    ABC_dataStructs BBB  = {.Name = "BBB",  .HexCmd = 0x00,     .Data = (void*) &BBB_Data}; 
    ABC_dataStructs CCC  = {.Name = "CCC",  .HexCmd = 0x00,     .Data = (void*) &CCC_Data}; 
    
}ABC_CommandList;

void main(){
    ABC_CommandList everything;

    everything.CCC.FullData = 0x000F;
    everything.BBB.use32BitColor = 0;
    int myint = everything.AAA.HexCmd;
}
```

Currently, I am having initializeing the values within the struct
`ABC_dataStructs AAA  = {.Name = "AAA", .HexCmd = 0x00,     .Data = (void*) &AAA_Data};` 
is invalid

Also and more importantly the assigning of the union is not working as intended. The current result only allows for `everything.AAA.Data` without being able to assign/read individual bits.

I also tried to explain the intent of the SW in order to avoid an "XY problem" and if I am approaching this wrong or you think of something better let me know. Thank You.

Note: [C struct, union pointer to struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124251/c-struct-union-pointer-to-struct?force_isolation=true) has another approach of putting `structs` in the `unions` instead of `unions` to the `structs`, but it doesn't help with my main issue of assigning these to a `void*`

Comment: You can assign any object you want to a `void*`.  The real question is why.

Comment: What prevents you from simply having three separate structs?

Comment: Coding on the edge: The `struct { various bit fields }` are _not_ certainly 32-bit is size - perhaps more.  `uint32_t spare` field adds as many problems as it solves.

Comment: `without being able to assign/read individual bits` You are able, access the pointer via proper pointer type `((ABC_EMPTY_DATA*)everything.AAA)->spare`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Explain, How is a union of a uint32_t not 32 bits? What am I missing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey 3 is just an example to show how I intend it to work. For example, XXX and YYY could share the same bits as BBB but with a different HexCmds. It would be easier to just be able to assign the BBB register to XXX & YYY without the need to create more structs.

Comment: @C-Low `uint32_t FullData;` is 32-bit. `struct  {  uint32_t use32BitColor :1;  uint32_t enableTimer: 1;  uint32_t fooTheBar :1; uint32_t spare: 29; } Bits;` is not certainly 32-bits in size, thus the `union` is not certainly 32-bit.  Packing is not required.  Bit field support other than `int, unsigned, _Bool` is implementation specific.  All might "work" for your implementation, yet code is not highly portable.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica This is interesting, I did not realize that only `int`, `unsigned` & `_Bool` were the only supported bitfield types. Noted & fixed.  However, I'm not sure how you can be so confident that a `uint32_t` is _certainly_ not 32-bits; I would expect it to be most of the time.

Comment: I am not saying `uint32_t` isn't 32-bit - that must be 32-bit.  The issue is not about `uint32_t`.   I am confident that the `struct` and hence the `union` could 32-bit or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having with the initialization is that you're defining a type and attempting to initialize it as if it's a variable at the same time.  You need to first define the struct, then initialize an instance of it:

```
typedef struct
{
    ABC_dataStructs AAA; 
    ABC_dataStructs BBB; 
    ABC_dataStructs CCC; 
}ABC_CommandList;

void main(){
    ABC_CommandList everything = {
        .AAA  = {.Name = "AAA",  .HexCmd = 0x00, .Data = &AAA_Data},
        .BBB  = {.Name = "BBB",  .HexCmd = 0x00, .Data = &BBB_Data},
        .CCC  = {.Name = "CCC",  .HexCmd = 0x00, .Data = &CCC_Data},
    };
    ...
```

Note also that it's not required to cast to/from a `void *`.

Then the problem here:

```
everything.CCC.FullData = 0x000F;
everything.BBB.use32BitColor = 0;
```

Is that `CCC` and `BBB` are of type `ABC_dataStructs`, and that type does not have fields named `FullData` or `use32BitColor`.  You would need to cast the `Data` member to the proper pointer type, then dereference that:

```
((ABC_CCC_DATA *)everything.CCC.Data)->FullData = 0x000F;
((ABC_BBB_DATA *)everything.BBB.Data)->use32BitColor = 0;
```

All that being said, there's a better way of modeling this data.  What you really want is a union of the 3 register types.  Then `ABC_dataStructs` would contain that union along with a separate field which flags which union to use.

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t spare  : 32;  //< Bits 0-31 not used
} ABC_EMPTY_DATA;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t use32BitColor          :  1;  //< Bit0 
    uint32_t enableTimer            :  1;  //< Bit1 
    uint32_t fooTheBar              :  1;   //< Bit2
    uint32_t spare                  : 29;  //< Bits 3-31 not used
} ABC_BBB_DATA;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t useInternalFrameTick   :  1;  //< Bit0 
    uint32_t useExternalFrameTick   :  1;  //< Bit1 
    uint32_t spare                  : 30;  //< Bits 2-31 not used
} ABC_CCC_DATA;

typedef struct
{
    char                *Name;
    unsigned int        HexCmd;
    union {
        ABC_EMPTY_DATA AAA;
        ABC_BBB_DATA   BBB;
        ABC_CCC_DATA   CCC;
        uint32_t FullData;
    };
}ABC_dataStructs;
```

Then you can define the following:

```
    ABC_CommandList everything = {
        .AAA  = {.Name = "AAA",  .HexCmd = 0x00, .AAA = {}},
        .BBB  = {.Name = "BBB",  .HexCmd = 0x00, .BBB = { .use32BitColor = 0 }},
        .CCC  = {.Name = "CCC",  .HexCmd = 0x00, .FullData = 0x000F },
    };
```

Comment: Awesome response, I don't know why I was trying to fill the types with data. I don't know why I was writing that. It was late?
Love the new union archetype. I felt that there was a cleaner way to do this I just couldn't get there. Thank you for your help.